# Which Tensorflow Package for Keras 2.3

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use Keras on my machine but I keep getting the error message 
"AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.backend' has no attribute 'get_graph'".

Stack Trace is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-dd13cebc6f04> in <module>
----> 1 import acgan

~/Documents/GitHub/Keras-GAN/acgan/acgan.py in <module>
  1 from __future__ import print_function, division
  2 
 ----> 3 from keras.datasets import mnist
  4 from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Reshape, Flatten, Dropout, multiply
  5 from keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Activation, Embedding, ZeroPadding2D

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/__init__.py in <module>
  1 from __future__ import absolute_import
  2 
 ----> 3 from . import utils
  4 from . import activations
  5 from . import applications

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py in <module>
  4 from . import data_utils
  5 from . import io_utils
 ----> 6 from . import conv_utils
  7 from . import losses_utils
  8 from . import metrics_utils

 /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py in <module>
  7 from six.moves import range
  8 import numpy as np
  ----> 9 from .. import backend as K
 10 
 11 

 /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py in <module>
 ----> 1 from .load_backend import epsilon
  2 from .load_backend import set_epsilon
  3 from .load_backend import floatx
  4 from .load_backend import set_floatx
  5 from .load_backend import cast_to_floatx

 /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/load_backend.py in <module>
 88 elif _BACKEND == 'tensorflow':
 89     sys.stderr.write('Using TensorFlow backend.\n')
 ---> 90     from .tensorflow_backend import *
 91 else:
 92     # Try and load external backend.

 /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in <module>
 52 
 53 # Private TF Keras utils
 ---> 54 get_graph = tf_keras_backend.get_graph
 55 # learning_phase_scope = tf_keras_backend.learning_phase_scope  # 
TODO
 56 name_scope = tf.name_scope

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.backend' has no attribute 'get_graph'
```

I googled the issue and found this

https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Deephi-DNNDK/Module-tensorflow-python-keras-backend-has-no-attribute-get/td-p/1022555

which tells me that it is tensorflow version related, but not which version to use. I am using Python3 on MacOS.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: As per the release notes, 2.3 Keras is compatible with both TF1.x and TF2 releases. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases

Comment: Please provide the stack trace of the error, so that it's easier to know why the problem is happening.

Comment: @ManojMohan yeah, I agree that there shouldn't be an issue since I am using TF2 and it says they are compatible. I posted the stack trace in the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce the error you observe with Keras 2.3.0 & tensorflow 2.0.0rc1. Although, I was able to start the training of acgan, I got a different error after one iteration: `Resource localhost/_AnonymousVar84/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist`.

I could successfully run the example with the following versions:

1. Keras 2.2.4/tensorflow 1.14.0
2. tensorflow 2.0.0rc1 and replace `keras` with `tensorflow.keras` in the imports.

Comment: I'm using `tf - 1.10.0` and `keras 2.3.0`, the second point works for me, i.e. replacing `keras` with `tensorflow.keras` can you explain why?