# Trouble importing Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Here is the complete code
top part runs fine till i import keras. 
I have tried installing and uninstalling keras, however the error is still there

## Classification template

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as my
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 3:13].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 13].values

# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
#Removing 1 Dummy Variable to avoid Dummy Variable Trap
X = X[:, 1:]


# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

# Part 2: Let's make the ANN
#Importing the keras library
import keras.backend
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# Initialising the ANN
classifier = Sequential()
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12379 Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58143135/which-tensorflow-package-for-keras-2-3

Comment: No, not really.

Answer (score 0):

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.backend' has no attribute 'get_graph'

Solution (as found in comments) was to install keras version 2.2.4

e.g:

```
pip install 'keras==2.2.4'
```

if you are above that version, you may try using this function instead:

```
keras.backend.image_data_format()
```

Comment: # Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

# Part 2: Let's make the ANN
#Importing the keras library
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# Initialising the ANN
classifier = Sequential()

Comment: Preferably by editing your original post, so that I can see more of it in a formatted way.

Comment: "I have tried installing and uninstalling keras" Can you try uninstalling Keras and using the Keras that is bundled with Tensorflow? And then use the change above for your imports, e.g. tensorflow.keras? Update your original post under your current code with whatever new error occurs if it does. You might also try tensorflow.python.keras for your imports if the prior does not work.

Comment: Hi , tensorflow.python.keras for your imports this does work for sequential. but what about the 'dense' import, any ideas for that.

Comment: This is the attribute error i am getting, i managed to check the path and found that this function does not exit. get_graph = tf_keras_backend.get_graph

Comment: # Private TF Keras utils
get_graph = tf_keras_backend.get_graph()
# learning_phase_scope = tf_keras_backend.learning_phase_scope  # TODO
name_scope = tf.name_scope

Comment: I am assuming you are using windows. Could you open your command prompt and type: python, import tensorflow.keras, tensorflow.keras.__version__ and then tell me what version it says?  The commas indicate separate commands. Would you also mind trying 'from tensorflow.keras import backend' within your current code.

Comment: I believe your problem can be solved by using keras version 2.2.4. If you are above the version, you may try the image_dim_ordering() function instead, which from what I can tell was the get_graph attribute's replacement.

Comment: Python version 3.6.4 and not sure how to chek the keras version 2.3.1

Comment: No such function as image_dim_ordering(),

Comment: Alright, so just to reiterate: you have keras uninstalled right now. So what I would like you to do is perform a pip install for specific version of keras: pip install 'keras==2.2.4'. From there, simply import from keras and not the tensorflow.keras bundle. Then try your get_graph attribute

Comment: The version 2.2.4 solved the issue. Thanks a lot for your help, highly appreciated @omoshiroiiI

Comment: No problem. Please make this the chosen answer and Ill edit the post for anyone else encountering this problem.

Comment: By the way, in the first link that I sent. The solution is clearly highlighted there to use keras 2.2.4. Please next time, try solutions given first